# Adding attributes to HTML element in an AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angular and am attempting to add validation to a directive based on attributes.  Here is how I use the directive:

```
<div sc-textbox data-bind-to="fieldToBind" data-field-name="fieldName" data-required="someValue != 'Office'"></div>
```

The data-required attribute may or may not be present.  The template for the directive is:

```
<input id="{{fieldName}}" name="{{fieldName}}" type="text" data-ng-model="bindTo" />
```

When the data-required attribute is present I would like to add data-ng-required="{{required}}" to the input.  How would I go about doing this?

The scope for the directive is:

```
scope: {
    'bindTo': '=',
    'fieldName': '@',
    'required': '='
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have limited scope, you need a boolean in your directive's scope that represents "someValue != 'Office'".

Or put someValue in scope and do this:

```
<input id="{{fieldName}}"
  data-ng-required="(someValue != 'Office') && required"
  name="{{fieldName}}" type="text" 
  data-ng-model="bindTo" />
```

**Update**

The attribute you want to add "data-ng-required" is a directive. You cannot dynamically add and remove directives from the DOM in Angular. If you really don't want "data-ng-required" in parts of your DOM, and you want this to be dynamic, the closest thing you can do is $compile and append this input as 2 templates-> one with required, and one without

Comment: the data-required="someValue != 'Office'" is just an example of a conditional required.  It could simply be data-required="true" or it could be left off all together and in this case I would not want the data-ng-required to be there at all.  I hope that made sense.

Comment: Is it not possible in Angular to modify the HTML of the template?  It seems like it should be possible to take:

    <input id={{fieldName}}" name="{{fieldName}}" type="text" data-ng-model="bindTo" />

and add some attributes such as data-ng-required or is the issue that I cant add directives?

You mention $compile.  Would it be possible to do this in the compile function?

Comment: Before you compile you can do whatever you want to the template. A simple example: dest.append($compile('<h1>{{stepNumber}}</h1>')($scope));

Comment: In that case how would I get access to the input to add an attribute?  Let assume for a second it is not the only html in the template.  In jQuery we would use the id but here the id is not even set yet.

Comment: This command is compiling the string '<h1>{{stepNumber}}</h1>'. So adding attributes to what will be a DOM element to this is a matter of how you generate the string

Answer (score 0):

Why not just leave ng-required there anyway. This is what it's for.

Comment: Because it may not be required.  This directive will be used for all textboxes on all forms and in some cases the field is required and in others it is not so I only want to add the ng-required when the directive has the data-required set.